# Explanation of Resolving paragraph 1.1.2 of Wiki "Names"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to everyone,

I am new of ROS and I am trying to go through all the ROS tutorials. I ended up in this page:

http://wiki.ros.org/Names#Graph

and I didn't understand how to interpret the resolving paragraph 1.1.2 'RESOLVING'.

Could you please explain it to me in a better way?

thanks a lot,
Fab.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194136/explanation-of-resolving-paragraph-1.1.2-of-wiki-%22names%22/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-04**:
Please clarify how you interpret the section and why you think that's incorrect. The terms you're asking about, base, global, private, and relative, are all defined in that section.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-11-18**:
I agree w tfoote. Anyway, detailed description below. Also maybe edit the question to include the phrase "graph resource name resolution" or something of the sort so others can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It basically means that when you write your code, you don't need to worry about there being the same name somewhere else.  All your resources - nodes, params, topics and services will be in the local scope. And then you can write a top level node to include all those nodes without any problem.

Edit: (based on comment to answer)

**Global**:
ROS has a global namespace - "/". If you define any of your graph resource names with a leading /, they will be global names. You can have a bunch of hierarchical namespaces  but as long as it starts with a "/", it is globally resolved.

Example: "/global/name/with/base"

**Base**:
That brings us to the second type - base names. Refer to the example above, every global name in ROS has a base which in this case is "base". You can look at it as the last name in the hierarchy and it doesn't have the "/"

**Relative**:
ROS also has something known as a default namespace. The default namespace can be specified but if not specified it is the global namespace - "/". Relative names DO NOT have the leading "/" and are resolved WRT this default namespace.

Example: If the default namespace were "/global/name", then "with/base" would be the relative name. Notice that there is no leading "/" to "with/base"

**Private**:
These names too are relative names, just that they use their nodes name as their default namespace. And they have to be specified with a leading "~".

Example: If "/global/name/with" was the name of the node, then the pvt. name "~base" would be the private name.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2014-10-03**:
Thanks for your reply but, what is the difference between base, relative, global, private ?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-10-24**:
Check additions to answer